# Get p:dataTable row data via p:selectOneMenu

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, datatable, row, selectonemenu

I have a dataTable which one of the columns contains a selectOneMenu (a.k.a dropDownList). Basically each row has a selectOneMenu which has a list of values. Is there a posibility to pass the row data or key whenever the selectOneMenu value has been selected? This way I can loop through my list of objects, allocate that specific object of the row and change the value
This is not my code but a simple example:

```
    <p:column headerText="Year">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.year}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Brand">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.brand}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="SelectOne">
      <p:selectOneMenu value="#{dtBasicView.selectedValue}">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{dtBasicView.listOfValues}" />
            <f:selectItems value="#{dtBasicView.listOfValues}"/>
      </p:selectOneMenu></p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: Have you seen any of the examples on the primefaces website or the manual, on this same topic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *This way I can loop through my list of objects, allocate that specific object of the row and change the value*

That effort is unnecessary. Just bind input component's value directly to the desired property.

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{car.selectedValue}">
```

This way JSF will transparently do all that effort for you.

If you intend to *listen* on the value change event so that you can do any additional actions, nest a `<p:ajax listener="#{bean.listener}">` inside the input component. You can even pass the current row object to the listener method.

```
<p:selectOneMenu ...>
    ...
    <p:ajax listener="#{bean.changeSelectedValue(car)}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

```
 public void changeSelectedValue(Car car) {
     // ...
 }
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question: I will try to explain it again:
Student object has the following values: Name, Surname and Attendance
Within the datatable there are three columns: Name (Shows just the name of the studet), Surname(Shows the surname) and Attendance (Has a selectOneMenu with two items: Present or Not Present). I implemented how you suggested: 
`<p:selectOneMenu value="#{student.isPresent}">
<p:ajax listener="#{dataTableView.onAttendanceChange}" />` But when the status is changed it only sets the value, but does not get the row. I need the row.

Comment: EDIT: `<p:selectOneMenu value="#{car.selectedValue}">` works when you select the row. I just need to change one value of the row